# vs code can't push my folders to git hub just because of this notification :git.openRepositoryInParentFolders

Tags: html, css

i have uninstall the app tried interacting with the CLI
still i cannot push my code to VS code

there is a messsage that my [that my problem [i cant push my code to vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLAI9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB6I9.png)

> There are 8120 untracked files which will be DELETED FROM DISK if discarded.
>
> This is IRREVERSIBLE, your current working set will be FOREVER LOST.
>
> <kbd>Discard 1880 Tracked Files</kbd>  <kbd>Discard all 10000 Files</kbd> <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

i tried uninstalling the app hoping the problem will be solved
but the message is consistent that there is an error which i cannot i dentify

Answer (score 1):

This is normal VS Code behaviour.

It's explained why this is done in VS Code's Source Control docs at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/faq#_why-isnt-vs-code-discovering-git-repositories-in-parent-folders-of-workspaces-or-open-files.

TL;DR: VS Code scans for git repositories in parent directories of the current workspace folder as a quality-of-life feature. But sometimes that's confusing to people, and sometimes leads to accidentally discarding changes/files from those parent-directory repositories, resulting in unintended data loss. That's why it's giving you that warning.

If you don't want VS Code to scan for git repositories in parent directories, use the `git.openRepositoryInParentFolders` setting. Quoting defaultSettings.json:

> ```json
> // Control whether a repository in parent folders of workspaces or open files should be opened.
> //  - always: Always open a repository in parent folders of workspaces or open files.
> //  - never: Never open a repository in parent folders of workspaces or open files.
> //  - prompt: Prompt before opening a repository the parent folders of workspaces or open files.
> "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "prompt",
> ```